# Group More Than One Controls At Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I had created a window with RelativeLayout and insterted two controls in it; one is GridView and the other one is WebView.

I will bind images to gridview to use like menu and i will load a html page in webview for ads.

But i have problems with these controls.
For example, if user scrolls gridview vertically it is disappearing behind webview however, in that i was expecting webview was slide with gridview too when user scroll gridview.

So i wonder, can i group these controls together to act simultaneously?

My another problem with orientation, when i turn my device to landscape mode webview is disappearing from screen.

Lastly if i set GridView's layout_height attribute fill_parent, i can't see WebView, so i set it as wrap_content. But this time WebView doesn't align at bottom, it aligns at GridView's after and there is space between screen bottom and webview.

```
     <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg480480">

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="45dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   />

        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/gridview"   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are some screen shots.

[image: First open (portrait mode)]

[image: same scren, landscape mode]

[image: same screen again, portait mode after landscape]

Comment: Try putting your RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main problem is that both the GridView and the Webview specify `layout_height="fill_parent"`. I guess you probably don't want the GridView to fill the whole parent area, so use `"wrap_content"` instead.

I don't know enough of the desired layout of the page but I would recommend using a LinearLayout to start and get comfortable. It really depends what the grid view and the web view should show and where your main content is.

In the example below I have simply assumed that your web view wants to take up the majority of the screen.

```
     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="45dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If the assumption is not correct then you would probably specify it the other way round (Webview=>`wrap_conent`)

Comment: thanks for answer, but webview doesn't showing with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the WebView layout code as below:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="45dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

FYI, `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` will display WebView at the bottom of the screen. and include  `android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"` inside the GridView.

Give a try to this layout code.

Comment: i added screenshots of current situation. as you can see its very weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 
    `android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"` 
in your gridview
also
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
in your webview

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg480480"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="45dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   />

        <WebView
             android:id="@+id/webView1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_below="@id/gridview"   />

</RelativeLayout>
```